# Celery unable to use redis

Tags: django, redis, celery, message-queue, django-celery

Trying to start Celery first time but issues error as below,
i have installed redis and its starting fine , but still somehow django seems to have issues with it ,

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/atif/Documents/celery_test/celery-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 263, in <module>
    class PrefixedStrictRedis(GlobalKeyPrefixMixin, redis.Redis):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Redis'
```

**Celery.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'celery_test.settings')



    app = Celery('celery_test',)
    
    app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
    
    # Load task modules from all registered Django apps.
    app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
    
    
    @app.task(bind=True)
    def debug_task(self):
        print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')
```

**Settings**

```
#celery stuff ---------------
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
```

**celery_module/tasks.py**

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks',)

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Comment: pip install -U celery[redis]

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Try to install `Redis` as in your virtual environment as well:

```
pip install Redis
```

Answer (score 5):

Install `redis` globally with

```
pip install redis
```

**OR (if you use `pipenv`)**

> The error in my case occurs as the `redis` package in the environment is not used when running

```
python -m celery -A *django_app* worker
```

If you use `pipenv` to manage you python environment you could run the command above as:

```
pipenv run python -m celery -A *django_app* worker
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Docker Compose,  me helped to add redis to file requirements.txt